# Unity 3.0 and DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, unity-container, prism

I try to add a new *Service Reference* to my class library project in Visual Studio 2013.

But before generating the code VS.NET throws this:

```
Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IWcfXXXService'] c:\Projects\...\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Domain.XXX
```

I'm using Prism 4.1 so Unity 3.0 is a must and it works fine - except while **generating** the service reference. And I'm really confused: whats the common in *Unity* and *DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter*?

If I remove Prism.UnityExtension then everything works fine.

What can I do? I do not want to change Unity 3.0 to 2.1.505.0 at every service reference refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism 4.1 is build against Unity 2.1.505.0 and the assemblies of Unity are shipped together with Prism 4.1

If you really want to use Unity 3.0 and you do not want to change the assembly references then you could use an assembly redirect to enforce that Unity 3.0 gets loaded, when Unity 2.1 is requested

Add the following to the configuration file of your application.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity"
                        publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                       />
      <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in application, publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.1.505.0"
                       newVersion="3.0.1304.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception"
                        publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                       />
      <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in application, publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.1.505.0"
                       newVersion="3.0.1304.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Aha, Prism 4.1 is with Unity 2.1 - I missed it. Thank you!